# Creating .NET Reference Assemblies directory automatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We're building a .NET 4.5 application, using VS 2012.  On developer machines, where VS 2012 is installed, there are no issues.  On machines where this is missing, they get an error while building the project which boils down to:

> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found.

I know that if I installed VS 2012 on these other machines, everything will work.  I don't want to have to do that.  I've tried installing a variety of things, all without any success:

- .NET 4.5 SDK
- .NET 4.5.1 SDK
- MS Build Tools
- Visual Studio 2012 SDK
- Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 8.1

After picking one machine and installing VS 2012 on it, I did before and after Process Monitor snapshots during a build.  The successful machine has this folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`, the unsuccessful machine does not.

I can copy the folder from my dev machine onto our build machines and other machines, but is there any thing I can install (short of Visual Studio), that sets this up correctly?

Comment: Well, the target machine is going to need to have the actual .NET Framework installed. Is this a server or are you building a desktop application to distribute to third parties?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Look at the Redistributables column. Also, if it's desktop you can bundle the framework along with it in the Setup & Deployment project

Comment: The errors aren't while running the application, they're while building it.  Should have made that clearer and have edited my question.

Comment: Why did you try the .NET 4.5.1 SDK when your target framework is 4.5, not 4.5.1? What happens if you install the .NET 4.5 SDK (part of the [Windows SDK for Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx), not for Windows 8.1)

Comment: I actually had installed the original .NET 4.5 SDK, forgot it in my list.  I gave the Windows 8 SDK a shot that you posted and it still had the same result.

Comment: I've ended up including the .NET 4.5 reference assembly folder in our source control and aiming MSBuild at it via the ```FrameworkPathOverride``` switch.  Works in my situation, but still doesn't answer if there is a cleaner way to do this, so if anyone knows, answer away.

Comment: I just tested on a clean Windows 7 system (on a virtual machine, all that's installed is what's available through Windows Updates, and the guest tools), and the .NET 4.5 SDK does cause `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5` to be created, exactly the path you're looking to see created. I have no idea why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Weird.  Well good to know, thanks for the information.

Answer (score -1):

Visual studio 2012 does not packed with .net framework 4.5.
you can download [.net framework 4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) and install it on your machine.

Comment: That's not going to help the OP. The reference assemblies aren't part of the runtime.